# JQuery-File-Upload Документация на русском

Tags: jquery

Уважаемые web программисты!
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли документация на русском языке на [сие](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) божественное творение?
Уж слишком много вопросов у меня =(

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/140400/

Comment: Или http://habrahabr.ru/post/158167/

Comment: Прошу прощения, но с гуглом я знаком и там нет искомого.

Comment: В таком случае учите английский=)

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, гугл переводчик решает XD